# power micro controller with 7.4V 400mah battery

Tags: power-supply, lithium-ion

I want o control a servo with a micro controller and I need more torque so I chose a 7.4V battery. Power my micro controller requires only 3.3V and obvious if I try to power it straight from this battery it will fry.
Is there a way I can get the 3.3V to the micro controller and the 7.4 to the servo all from this same battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a 3.3v voltage regulator for your micro-controller like LM2937-3.3. The schematic shows you how to connect your servo to the micro-controller. The servo uses the 7.8v from your battery and is controlled from your micro-controller with a PWM  output. Double-check the maximum power supply your servo can handle just to be sure.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2qdLW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regulator like an LD1117V33, but it's going to dissipate the extra 4.1V as heat. With only 400mAh available, you might want to consider a more efficient switching regulator like the LM2576.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a 3.3V regulator. There are plenty on the market.